# How to add SplitViewController on the third view in the application

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I need some help.
I had created login page from that page user with redirect to tableview.
After selecting row the next view which i want to show is splitviewcontroller.
I cannot add these please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find alternative option for this because it is not possible to add SplitViewController on other then Window.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following tutorial for using splitviewcontroller 
[SplitViewController Tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/04/05/ipad-programming-tutorial-hello-world/)

Comment: Sorry but i didn't require this way i want to add splitview controller after 2 - 3 views.